# How to Send Item Attributes with Google Tag Manager Custom events

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

I created a custom tag for order request and push them via data layer. but item attributes does not appear inside the item properties.

```
<script>
        dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });  // Clear the previous ecommerce object.
        dataLayer.push({
        event: "add_to_wishlist",
        ecommerce: {
            value:{{ $orderRequest->total_amount }},
            currency: "USD",
            items: [
                @foreach($orderRequest->requestItems as $key => $requestItem)   
                            {
                                item_id : "{{ $requestItem->item->sku }}",
                                item_name: "{{ $requestItem->item->title }}",
                                price: {{ $requestItem->total_amount }},                
                                quantity: {{ $requestItem->quantity }},
                                item_category:"{{  count($requestItem->item->tags) > 0 ? (count($requestItem->item->tags->first()->parentCategory()) > 0 ? $requestItem->item->tags->first()->parentCategory()->first()->name:'' ) : '' }}",
                                item_category2:"{{ count($requestItem->item->tags) > 0 ? $requestItem->item->tags->first()->name : '' }}",
                            },
                @endforeach
            ]
        }
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: The `tag` you mean GTM's tag? This snippet should put on the website's code since you are using the `$orderRequest->requestItems` which is your frontend or backend variable.